# How to call Application getDatabase in Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I downloaded the Room BasicSample app from here:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components

This sample is a readonly database. There is no example to insert a single entity. I am modifying it, and struggling to figure out how to call the getDatabase so I can do a simple insert on the db on a button click -
 getDatabase().wordDao().insert(...) ?

How do I get access to the singleton BasicApp and call getDatabase method, and where do I call it from?

Any help is appreciated.

**single Insert**

```
@Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
void insert(WordEntity word);
```

**AppDatabase.java** (not sure if this insert method goes here)

```
private static void insert(final AppDatabase database, final WordEntity word) {
        database.wordDao().insert(word);
}
```

**BasicApp.java**

```
public class BasicApp extends Application {

    private AppExecutors mAppExecutors;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mAppExecutors = new AppExecutors();
    }

    public AppDatabase getDatabase() {
        return AppDatabase.getInstance(this, mAppExecutors);
    } // ==> how do I get access to this?

    public DataRepository getRepository() {
        return DataRepository.getInstance(getDatabase());
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a better example for insert and delete with ViewModel and LiveData: https://github.com/SubhrajyotiSen/Borrow/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/subhrajyoti/borrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you are accessing BasicApp class from an activity or service you can just call `((BasicApp)getApplication()).getDatabase()`.

Comment: Both answers are good but this one works if you don't have a view.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a little on what class you are working in.

if it is an activity method (like onCreate):

```
BasicApp basicApp = (BasicApp) this.getApplicationContext();
AppDatabase appDatabase = basicApp.getDatabase();
//... do work here
```

If you only have a view (like in an onClickListener which passes a view as an arg):

```
BasicApp basicApp = (BasicApp) view.getContext().getApplicationContext();
AppDatabase appDatabase = basicApp.getDatabase();
//... do work here
```